# Function that prints all sequences of 32 digits in C

Tags: c, binary, numbers, permutation

Sorry for this question but i'm trying to optimize a C function that prints all sequences of 32 digits, such that each digit in the sequence is a 0 or 1, for example :

00000000000000000000000000000000
...
01010101010101010101010101010101
...
01000000010000000100000001000000

i did come out with a solution but it have 3 for loop nested together and it's quite time consuming, i was wondering if it is possible to have a simpler algorithm.

Thanks for your help

Andrea

Hi all,thanks for your answers :) at the end i used the solution following your help:

void binary_permutation(void)
{

```
unsigned int i=0;
char str[32];

do{
    itoa(i++, str, 2);

        printf("binary: %s\n", str);
}
while (i);
```

}

Thanks again

Andrea

Comment: Without seeing the code you have right now, nobody will be able to answer.

Comment: `unsigned int x = 0; do{printasbinary(x++);}while(x);`. `printasbinary(unsigned int)` is left as an exercise.

Comment: You do realize that you're trying to print 128 billion characters, right? That's going to be time consuming any way you do it.

Comment: Hi all,thanks for your answers :) at the end i used the solution following your help:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use recursion or backtracking, it saves you all the pain of nested loops(yes, this function takes time to run!)
[This article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) explains this well. 
good luck!